# How to embed codeigniter script into external php script

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, include

l have a index file of my website in

`localhost-->mywebsite-->index.php` (this is my external script)

and i have build a registration form with codeigniter.

I can use the registration form using url http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form.

But how can i attach that registration form into my website index file.

using `include_once"../codeigniter/index.php/form";` in my external php script(`index.php` of my website) is not working.

However if i make that `'form'` the default controller file and use the following code from external php script 
`include_once "codeigniter/index.php";` it works well. but what if i need other controller files but not just `'form'`?

**Update:**

I can also link to that file from external php script as:
`<a href="codeigniter/index.php/form>Register</a>.`
But not include. Whenever i include it displays no such file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if i understood you correctly you want to use `codeigniter's` form in some other php website, actually idea to do such thing is **wrong** (as you can't normally control your form action link etc better to build same for in other website directly), but answer for your question is following trick

Place this code in your other website where you want to have codeigniter form included

```
$output = shell_exec('php ABSOLUTE_PATH/codeigniter/index.php form index');
// where "ABSOLUTE_PATH" is absolute path to your codeigniter project
// "form" is your controller name 
// "index" action name
echo $output; // will echo form html generated by codeigniter
```

Comment: this helps me but when i input  values in the form. the form validation notices such as  'insert at least 3 characters', 'password not matching' etc. seems to be in new page instead i need it to display in my website.

Comment: i did not get, if that form in codeigniter has related validation js files induced in view then there is no way to exclude it at your second website

Comment: i have that related validation js files in my website folder not in codeigniter view. it won;t work that way??

Comment: ok lets understand each other so i will be able to help you pls answer on following questions `1)` you have 2 different websites one build on `codigniter` second one `pure php` ? `2)` if websites are 2  - you are trying to load same form from codigniter one to second website ? `3)` if there is only one website build on `codigniter` website why you just not include that view in other view ?

Comment: Yes to q.n.  1 and 2.  i am wanting to include codeigniter website to website built with normal php that donot contain view files.

Comment: ok now regarding that validation part. lets label in text for easy talking your `codigniter website` as `CW` and `pure php website` as `PPW`. 1) you have in your PPW some validation js scripts and want to validate through it included from CW html form ? 2) do you have all validation scripts included in your PPW html `<header>` ? 3) have you call init validation on document ready for included CW form in some script of PPW ?

Comment: Yes to 2.  no and how to 3.

Comment: What type of js validation script is present in your PPW ? jquery validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/ or ?

Comment: Coming to the start, i have the website in which i include the codeigniter controller file from the code you stated above. this also contains js files and others. but when the validation notices completely appears from another new page.

Comment: So i don't understand what you are doing already, what other new page you are talkin about ..., You have to create some other new question in Stackoverflow with detailed explanation and screenshots about your validation problems

Comment: I will move all the websites files in codeigniter view and set it up that way.

Comment: Yes that would be best

Comment: shell_exec may not available in shared hosting when you goes to live

Answer (score 2):

In localhost-->mywebsite-->index.php, you could try this:

```
<?php include_once('/codeigniter/index.php/form'); ?>
```

If not you can move your index.php code into a codeigniter view and set it up that way.

Comment: include_once "codeigniter/index.php/form"; doesnot seem to work.

Comment: moving index into codeigniter view and setting up that way was a good idea but can't i use that code?

Answer (score 2):

try using below code...

```
<?php  $data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form/");
$html_encoded = htmlentities($data);
echo $html_encoded;
?>
```

In the above code we get all contents of the url in `$data` variable and then use **htmlentities** on that for html encoding...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Ashish Raj this includes the whole script.